# How to count a number occurence in an excel [Range] using formula?

Tags: excel-formula

I used this formula **`=SUM( --ISNUMBER( FIND( number, Range, 1 ) ) )`** to count how many times a number occurred in a row, but as you can see in the sample image in the **row 2** **Col D** the highlighted it doesn't count again the same number in the same cell.
[image: PrintScreen-]
[*Sample Image Link*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QW0Vn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: **`=SUM(LEN(Range) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Range, number, "")))`** and then turn it into an array formula by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter rather than Enter after you enter the formula into the cell.